# Why is Visual Studio using EqualityComparer on string when auto-generating GetHashCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, gethashcode

As of version 15.6.7, Visual Studio 2017 for the following class:

```
class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

generates this `GetHashCode` method (the numbers vary):

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    var hashCode = 1460282102;
    hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + Id.GetHashCode();
    hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Name);
    return hashCode;
}
```

Why is the string hash retrieved using the `EqualityComparer<>` and not just by calling `String.GetHashCode()` instance method? Is it just because of the null-check performed by the default comparer?

It seems to me that using the equality comparer is an overhead.

Comment: You can just return zero from the GetHashCode is you Equal function does a full compare.  The GetHashCode() runs before the Equal Method() and is suppose to be a first check of not equal.

Comment: " Is it just because of the null-check performed by the default comparer?". Do you need more of a reason? What would happen if it "just [called the] `String.GetHashCode()` instance method" and `Name` was `null` ?

Comment: @AakashM, I understand the null check is needed. However the equality comparer call is quite expensive null check.

Comment: @JosefBláha why do you think it's expensive? The reference source suggests that literally all it does it null-check, then defer to the object's `GetHashCode`

Comment: @AakashM, because before you get there you need to call `Default` property (possibly allocating `ObjectComparer<string>`) and then call virtual `GetHashCode`. Granted, in most cases this smells with premature optimization. Back to the original question: I agree, that using the comparer is a good readable way of solving the null check.